# Building a directory listing via batch script. Need to exclude some directories. How?

Tags: cmd, dir

I work with hundreds of thousands of folders/files, most of which have certain log files. It takes a lot of time to manually navigate through the folders to grab the logs, so Ive been using a script to do it.

Its a 2 parter. First part runs overnight to parse all of the directories (they change daily and new logs are added very often, so I index everything nightly to keep the index current).

This first part is automatic and I never touch it, it just runs nightly. Output goes to a txt file, which is used when I execute the second script.

Second script is where I put in keywords of what log I am looking for. This script relies on the txt output from the first script to quickly locate the file and pull it down.

(The reason I do it this way is because its a 5 second task to parse 300,000 line text file looking for a file, and its a 15-30 minute job to search (index all of the network shares). This way I can get my logs in 5 seconds and not 30+ minutes).

Prior to last week the log directories consisted of about 5000 files and folders. This past weekend IT switched over to a new system, and it is now consisting of over 500,000 files and folders. They dumped archives, and a bunch of other files in there that I do not need.

First script used to index it in about 10-15 minutes (its a network share, actually 4 network shares), no problem overnight. While now this is a 4+ hour feat. I need to be able to exclude certain directories during indexing thereby reducing the 500,000 file/folder count back down to under 5,000.

Ive been using this command to index:

```
dir /b /-d /-p /s /A:-D > C:\output.txt
```

I need have the indexing skip any directory containing the words "Common" or "Old" in them, and potentially others as well. The goal is to save time by not going inside of these directories at all.

I tried looking into PowerShell to do this, but I know nothing about it.

I need the output to be in the following format:

```
C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\GeForce332.21Driver\Display.Driver\dbInstaller.exe
C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\GeForce332.21Driver\Display.Driver\DisplayDriver.nvi
C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\GeForce332.21Driver\Display.Driver\DisplayDriverExt.dll
C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\GeForce332.21Driver\Display.Driver\license.txt
C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\GeForce332.21Driver\Display.Driver\mcu.ex_
C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\GeForce332.21Driver\Display.Driver\nvae.inf
C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\GeForce332.21Driver\Display.Driver\nvak.inf
C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\GeForce332.21Driver\Display.Driver\nvapi.dl_
C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\GeForce332.21Driver\Display.Driver\nvapi64.dl_
C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\GeForce332.21Driver\Display.Driver\nvcompiler.dl_
C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\GeForce332.21Driver\Display.Driver\nvcompiler32.dl_
C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\GeForce332.21Driver\Display.Driver\nvcplsetupeng.exe
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=."
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /s /ad "%sourcedir%\*" ^|findstr /v /i /l /g:q22903564.txt'
  ) DO ( FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN ('dir /b /a-d "%%a" 2^>nul') DO ECHO(%%a\%%b
)
)>newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q22903564.txt` containing exclusion words for my testing.
Produces newfile.txt.

Naturally, choice of `sourcedir`, `q22903564.txt` and `newfile.txt` are all in your court...

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: make a tempfile
:maketemp
SET "tempfile=%temp%\%random%"
IF EXIST "%tempfile%*" (GOTO maketemp) ELSE (ECHO.>"%tempfile%a")

SET "sourcedir=."

:: get a dir listing from the root
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /ad "%sourcedir%\*" ^|findstr /v /i /l /g:q22903564.txt'
 ) DO (ECHO("%%~fa")
)>"%tempfile%b"

:again

(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%tempfile%b") DO (
 FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN (
 'dir /b /ad "%%~a\*" ^|findstr /v /i /l /g:q22903564.txt'
 ) DO FOR /f "delims=" %%c IN ('ECHO("%%~a\%%b"^|findstr /x /v /i /l /g:"%tempfile%b"') DO ECHO "%%~c"
)
)>"%tempfile%c"

FOR %%a IN ("%tempfile%c") DO SET /a sizec=%%~za
IF %sizec% gtr 0 TYPE "%tempfile%c">>"%tempfile%b"&GOTO again

(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%tempfile%b") DO (
 FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%%~a\*" 2^>nul'
 ) DO ECHO(%%~a\%%b
)
)>newfile.txt

DEL "%tempfile%*"

GOTO :eof
```

Well - need to charge you extra for doing what, according to some, is impossible.

---

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: make a tempfile
:maketemp
SET "tempfile=%temp%\%random%"
IF EXIST "%tempfile%*" (GOTO maketemp) ELSE (ECHO.>"%tempfile%a")

SET "sourcedir=."

:: get a dir listing from the root
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /ad "%sourcedir%\*" ^|findstr /v /i /l /g:q22903564.txt'
 ) DO (ECHO("%%~fa")
)>"%tempfile%b"

SET /a sizec=0

:again
SET "skipcnt=usebackq"
IF %sizec% gtr 0 (
 FOR /f %%a IN ('type "%tempfile%b" ^|find /c /v ""') DO SET "skipcnt=usebackqskip=%%a"
 TYPE "%tempfile%c">>"%tempfile%b"
)

(
FOR /f "%skipcnt%delims=" %%a IN ("%tempfile%b") DO (
 FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN (
 'dir /b /ad "%%~a\*" ^|findstr /v /i /l /g:q22903564.txt'
 ) DO FOR /f "delims=" %%c IN ('ECHO("%%~a\%%b"^|findstr /x /v /i /l /g:"%tempfile%b"') DO ECHO "%%~c"
)
)>"%tempfile%c"

FOR %%a IN ("%tempfile%c") DO SET /a sizec=%%~za
IF %sizec% gtr 0 GOTO again

(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%tempfile%b") DO (
 FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%%~a\*" 2^>nul'
 ) DO ECHO(%%~a\%%b
)
)>newfile.txt

DEL "%tempfile%*"
GOTO :eof
```

Third time's a charm. This version works out how many lines of directory it's already processed and skips those lines when re-processing the concatenated lists b and c. IOW, it only processes the additions.

And in typing this, I've realised there's another little simplification... have to wait for morning tea, though...

---

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: make a tempfile
:maketemp
SET "tempfile=%temp%\%random%"
IF EXIST "%tempfile%*" (GOTO maketemp) ELSE (ECHO.>"%tempfile%a")

SET "sourcedir=."

:: get a dir listing from the root
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /ad "%sourcedir%\*" ^|findstr /v /i /l /g:q22903564.txt'
 ) DO ECHO(%%~fa
)>"%tempfile%c"

SET /a sizec=0

:again
SET "skipcnt=usebackq"
IF %sizec% neq 0 FOR /f %%a IN ('type "%tempfile%b" ^|find /c /v ""') DO SET "skipcnt=usebackqskip=%%a"
TYPE "%tempfile%c">>"%tempfile%b"

(
FOR /f "%skipcnt%delims=" %%a IN ("%tempfile%b") DO (
 FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN (
 'dir /b /ad "%%a\*" ^|findstr /v /i /l /g:q22903564.txt'
 ) DO ECHO(%%a\%%b
)
)>"%tempfile%c"

FOR %%a IN ("%tempfile%c") DO SET /a sizec=%%~za
IF %sizec% gtr 0 GOTO again

(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%tempfile%b") DO (
 FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%%a\*" 2^>nul'
 ) DO ECHO(%%a\%%b
)
)>newfile.txt

DEL "%tempfile%*"
GOTO :EOF
```

This time for sure! (no lion's roar thought)

I realised that the re-filtering against the original tempfileb content was redundant - and removing that meant that the quoting regime to overcome awkward characters could be scaled back. Then in reality the original file was the original addition (tempfilec) to an empty tempfileb, so - a little reorganisation and hand-waving (because 'skip=0' is invalid) and the result is that the only directories that are scanned later are thos that have beed added in the last iteration, optimising the directory-scan methodology.

Now the consequences are that the resultant list will be \a\, \b\, \c\, \a\a1\, \b\b1\, and so on - but a simple `sort` of the result should take care of that, if required.

Comment: That is pretty cool. Question for you though... does it still go through the directories on exclusion list or does it skip them correctly... to illustrate. lets say I have 3 folders
    folder1 <has no folders inside>
    folder2 <has no folders inside>
    folder3 <has 10000000 folders and files inside>

i run the script on root. And have folder 3 in exclusion... will it just stop after 1 and 2 without going inside of 3? or will it still go through 3 and all the folders/files in there but not have them in final output? Sorry if dumb question but that script you gave is pretty damn complicated

Comment: It creates a full list of the directories first - not the files, and then scans for files in the directories that pass through the `findstr` filter for directories `/v` - not-matching `/i` - case-insensitive `/l` literally `/g` any entry in the file... So - it should be reasonably fast. It would be possible to stop the directory-scan when a 'go no further' entry is detected, but if you think this is complicated, it's a cinch compared with optimising for minimum directory-scans...

Comment: Hmm, yeah my main problem is going through all of the directories. having a 300000 line txt file in the end versus 1000 line doesnt matter for my purposes, both take a few seconds to look through, they are local and with modern CPU very fast to parse. What takes forever though is indexing all paths.. is there any way like you said to "optimize for minimum directory-scans" ? I need to not scan through all 300,000 folders. That takes 4+ hours on network shares. I need the "indexing" to stop scanning any deeper once it hits a keyword in folder name. This could potentially cut out 75% of the dirs.

Comment: You'll need to do it in powershell or some other scripting language then, a batch file isn't powerful enough to do this.

Comment: Thanks of that expanded version Magoo. In that expanded version, how deep does it look for the exclusion list? Does it only look in the first 2 subfolders? or does it go all the way down until it hits a keyword? Because what I am working with has 5 to 10 sub-directories.

Comment: All the way. The first block builds a list of directories-passining-the-filter into tempfileb. The second uses tempfileb as a list of directories to scan using the same filter and builds tempfilec. If c is not zero-length, then it's appended to b and the process repeated until there are no more additional entries in c. Then the files are detected using the final list in b. Hmm- I've also seen another little speed-up I could do, but that'll have to wait 'til after breakfast...

Comment: Thanks magoo, Ive tried first and 4th iterations you posted above. but both give "Could Not Find the File Specified" spam on the screen for a few seconds before exiting. I have an exlusion file with about 20 lines (one word per line), but ive tried removing all but 1, and ive even tried hardcoding working dir as F:\ still same result.  I dont see temp files being created anywhere (i tried putting in a pause to try figure out whats going on, no temp files at all created).

Comment: If it makes any easier to communicate maybe we should do this over email? I am never sure if you can see my replies or not.

Comment: Certainly - My easy address is billious_1954@hotmail.com - SO really doesn't have the facility for a debugging session...

Answer (score 0):

This may help: it excludes the terms in line 3 where you see `"Common Old"`

It creates a list of the folders, filters out the excluded terms, and uses the remaining folders to create the list.

If you only want `*.log *.txt` files etc then it could be made more efficient again - otherwise remove the `*.log *.txt` terms in the batch file in line 7

```
@echo off
dir /b /ad /s /-p > "C:\output.txt"
findstr /v /i "Common Old" "C:\output.txt" >"C:\output2.txt"
del "C:\output.txt"

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("C:\output2.txt") do (
   pushd "%%a"
      for /f "delims=" %%b in ('dir *.log *.txt /b /-p /a-d') do >>"C:\output.txt" echo(%%a\%%b
   popd
)
```